# Transformations of joint probability function

Tags: probability-distributions, transformation

The joint pdf of X, Y, and Z is given by

$f(x,y,z) = 8xy\,\mathsf e^{-z}$ for $0≤x<y≤1, z>0$  (0 otherwise)

What is the joint pdf of $U=X/Y$ and $V = Y$?

My idea is that we should create another dummy variable for $Z$ and then use the Jacobian for 3x3 matrices. Is this correct or do I have another alternative?

Comment: Find the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ by integrating out $z$ and then use $2\times 2$ Jacobian

Comment: Alright, Thank you in advance

Comment: Since $Y=V$ you don't even need a $2\times 2$ Jacobian.  Just note $X=UY$ and so immediately $\lVert \mathrm J^{\small X,Y}_{\small U,Y}\rVert =\left\lvert\tfrac{\partial uy}{\partial u}\right\rvert$